# Syntax Error, Unexpected keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
    <%= @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class='post_wrapper'>
    <h2 class="title"><%= link_to post.title, post%></h2>

    <p class="date">
    <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at%>ago
    </p>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I am getting an error saying "unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' '.freeze;" when I reload on my localhost for the above code. Not sure why it would be throwing that error.

I have another file that also has <% end %> and I'm not getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a close parenthesis `)` after `time_ago_in_words(post.created_at`

The reason it said it found the unexpected keyword `end` is because it was expecting a close parenthesis up at that spot and kept looking for it, through the end of the file, without finding it. Therefore, the keyword `end` was unexpected because it was expecting a `)` to precede it at some point.